# Move rects in canvas at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, canvas

I have created multiple rectangles in the Canvas element. The primary goal is to move all of them in the direction of the touch or mouse move event. Maybe the answer is in front of me, but right now I am blind :(

Here is the example code on [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/qsT1TvMptBzY3hox?preview)

Code:

```
var context = {
  collection: [],
  canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx: canvas.getContext('2d'),
  isMoving: false
};

for (let f = 0; f < 3; f++) {
    var item = {
        x: (Math.random() * 200),
        y: (Math.random() * 100),
        w: 50,
        h: 50
    };

    context.collection.push(item);
}

drawAll(context);
```

Touch event handler:

```
context.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) { onTouchHandler(e, context) }, false)
context.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) { onTouchHandler(e, context) }, false);
context.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) { onTouchHandler(e, context) }, false);

function onTouchHandler(e, context) {
    var touch = getTouchCoordinates(e.pageX, e.pageY, context.canvas);

    switch (e.type) {
        case 'mousedown':
            context.isMoving = true;
            break;
        case 'mousemove':
            if(context.isMoving === true){
                console.log(touch);

                //TODO: move all objects by the cursor...
                for (let f = 0; f < context.collection.length; f++) {
                    var item = context.collection[f];
                }

                //drawAll(context);
            }
            break;
        case 'mouseup':
            context.isMoving = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Draw rectangles:

```
function drawAll(context){
  var canvas = context.canvas,
      ctx = context.ctx,
      shapes = context.collection;

  clearAll(ctx, canvas);

  for (let x = 0; x < shapes.length; x++) {
      var element = shapes[x];
      ctx.rect(element.x, element.y, element.w, element.h);
      ctx.stroke();
  }

}
```

Clear rects:

```
function clearAll(ctx, canvas){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Get touch x,y:

```
function getTouchCoordinates(pageX, pageY, canvas) {
    var element = canvas,
        offsetX = 0,
        offsetY = 0,
        currentX,
        currentY;

    if (element.offsetParent != undefined) {
        do {
            offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
            offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent))
    }

    currentX = pageX - offsetX;
    currentY = pageY - offsetY;

    return {
        x: currentX,
        y: currentY
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code a bit just to show how you could move the rectangles. I'm not checking for mouse press or release.

```
var context = {
  collection: [],
  canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx: canvas.getContext('2d'),
  isMoving: false
};

// rectangle positions
for (let f = 0; f < 3; f++) {
    var item = {
        x: (Math.random() * 200),
        y: (Math.random() * 100),
        w: 50,
        h: 50
    };

    context.collection.push(item);
}

// listen
context.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",  (e) => onMoveHandler(e));

// Draw
drawAll();

function onMoveHandler(e) {
    //console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY)

    for (let f = 0; f < context.collection.length; f++) {
        var item = context.collection[f];

        var xdifference = item.x - e.pageX
        item.x = (xdifference < 0) ? item.x + 1 : item.x -1

        var ydifference = item.y - e.pageY
        item.y = (ydifference < 0) ? item.y + 1 : item.y -1
    }
    drawAll()
}

function drawAll(){

  // clear all 
  clearAll();

  for (let x = 0; x < context.collection.length; x++) {
      var element = context.collection[x];
      context.ctx.rect(element.x, element.y, element.w, element.h);
      context.ctx.stroke();
  }

}

function clearAll(){
  context.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
}
```

If you want a more "natural" looking movement towards the mouse, you can calculate the x and y difference using the Pythagorean theorem:

```
var xdifference = e.pageX - item.x
var ydifference = e.pageY - item.y

let distance = Math.sqrt(xdifference * xdifference + ydifference * ydifference)
item.x += (xdifference / distance)
item.y += (ydifference / distance)
```

In the plunker example it's not 100% accurate because the x,y offset of the element on the page isn't used in the calculation :)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I did not use x, y in plunker on purpose, just created a simple playground. I was hoping if you can give me more information on how to get direction steps in order to change the position of the elements, not toward the mouse. 
Example, if you start heading to the left, at the same time position of the elements are changing by the number of steps made with the mouse. This would be helpful if there are more then 15 elements and you wont to move all of them at the same time to the desired direction and stop where there is no movement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

1. "mousedown" - used to store initial x,y of the mouse
2. "mousemove" - used to move whole canvas section just to simulate the movement of the rectangles and store offset (x,y)
3. "mouseup" - the key point is to use the stored offset (x,y) and set the positions of the rectangles, after that reset canvas position and redraw rectangles with new values.

Maybe there is more elegant way to do it, but right now this will do the trick :)